# Php code not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a pie chart for the percentage of males and females in a table in my database.
I've Written the following code but it is not working. Please help.

```js
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ganesh"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$sql1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = \'Male\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM student");
$sql2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = \'Female\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Female_count FROM student");
echo "
<script  type = 'text/javascript'  src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);      
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Gender', 'Number'],
['Male',   ".$sql1."],
['Female',  ".$sql2."]
]);
var options = {
title: 'First Year'
 };
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
";

?>

<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">chart</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add script inside echo and put that inside php code , do it similar i have added a snippet below.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ganesh"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$sql1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = \'Male\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM student");
$sql2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = \'Female\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Female_count FROM student");
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);      
    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Gender', 'Number'],
    ['Male',   ".$sql1."],
    ['Female',  ".$sql2."]
    ]);
    var options = {
    title: 'First Year'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
";

?>

  <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors but the chart is not getting displayed. How do I do that?

Comment: hmm then there is only one problem i guess your sql statement is having error

Comment: you right click on browser, and then click on inspect element, then go to console and check what error is showing there

Comment: Also remember to execute php you must be running services like xampp, wampp etc. because its a server side scripting

Comment: Also if you can go to phpmyadmin and try out your queries on database and check them if they are executing for real or giving some error ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'load' of undefined

Comment: the sql queries which I run in phpmyadmin are working fine.

Comment: okay have you added google script link ?, `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\stack.php on line 10

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>   .....This is line 10

Comment: okay i got it , remove type="text/javascript" from your script tag

Comment: or make it type='text/javascript' , you can see it from my above given example

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'https' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\stack.php on line 10........the error I get when I remove type="text/javascript"....I also tried 'text/javascript' but it is showing the same error

Comment: could you update your code in your question so that i can check it ?

Comment: add another section below the prev question and mark it as update: and then post new code below that

Answer (score 0):

For your new updated code :

```
  <?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ganesh"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$sql1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = \'Male\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM student");
$sql2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = \'Female\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Female_count FROM student");

echo ' <script  type = "text/javascript"  src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>';

echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);      
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Gender', 'Number'],
['Male',   ".$sql1."],
['Female',  ".$sql2."]
]);
var options = {
title: 'First Year'
 };
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
";

?>
```

Comment: if this solves your problem mark this answer as correct